# Athena error: Please ensure target table is an external table. (for Governed Table)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-lake-formation

I have created a governed table in aws lakeformation with all the proper permissions assigned. But when i run INSERT INTO query in Athena I am getting this error saying

```
    Please ensure target table orcsiteorderidx is an external table.
This query ran against the "governedb" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support.
```

But when I edit the table in lakeformatiom and add EXTERNAL TRUE, I am getting same error. Can someone please help me out in finding the issue.

[image: Athena error]

[image]

Comment: Do you know what an external table is? Adding a property / tag to the table certainly does not make it an external table.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/governed-tables-io.html + https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lf-governed-tables.html *"To help ensure secure and reliable transactions, Athena supports read operations using AWS Lake Formation governed tables"* - what makes you think you can *write* data into governed tables using athena?

Comment: @luk2302, i missed it, ok so Athena only supports read operation for governed table. But if i want to insert/update a row how do i do it? I'm really missing something to understand, can you please explain it in simple terms? Thanks

Comment: You need to read up on what governed tables are: *"Writes – When you add table data as new Amazon S3 objects, you call the UpdateTableObjects API operation to add those objects to the governed table manifest. You typically make one or more of these calls within a transaction, which can be rolled back if there are any failures. To call the UpdateTableObjects API, the principal needs INSERT and DELETE Lake Formation permissions on the governed table."*. (excerpt from the first link I posted)

Comment: AWS recently made GA of this feature in Apr 2022, i.e., ACID compliance, Insert/update over S3 objects using Apache Iceberg, time travel, etc., maybe you can read this document, and see if it helps, https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/amazon-athena-acid-transactions-powered-apache-iceberg/ & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1v666EXCJw

Comment: @Yuva are you sure that works with LakeFormation governed tables? Sounds like the two are unrelated and not compatible.

Comment: @Yuva iceberg is a great option but it doesn't support in governed table as of now.